# Implementation of WMS SOAP Client

Tags: wms, soap

I'm currently working on the implementation of a Geospatial Mapping web application.  I/We  need this to be a WMS SOAP Client,  rather than the usual WMS requests via HTTP/REST.

In order to facilitate this effort I’m thinking that we could do one of the following:

1: Is there a way ( plugin, configuration) to enable GeoServer to respond to WMS SOAP requests ?

2: Does anyone know of  a  WMS SOAP Server which is open / public / internet  accessible ?

ALL OF THE URLs BELOW  Responded With

internal error - server connection terminated
Description: internal error - server connection terminated

http://193.232.117.144/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/html/mapFiles/maingis.map&request=GetCapabilities

### http://132.156.97.59/cgi-bin/canmin_en-ca_ows?request=GetCapabilities

### -

### -

-

Comment: In regards to #2)     http://gis.fema.gov/REST/services/NSS/OpenShelters/MapServer

Comment: The syntax in your above requests is incomplete, you need to specify the service parameter as well, so that's 'http://132.156.97.59/cgi-bin/canmin_en-ca_ows?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&' and `http://193.232.117.144/cgi-bin/mapserv?map=/var/www/html/mapFiles/maingis.map&request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&`